# How to add class when active menu - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery script that will add clas to a specfic li. The first 3 li 
it add class but if clicking on 4th to last li it does not apply. Please 
help me about this:

```
html:

<ul class="sidebar-menu" id = "navigation">
    <li><a href="www.site.com/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li> 
    <li><a href="wwww.site.com/mycoupon">My Coupons</a></li> 
    <li><a href="www.site.com/member">View Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.site.com/update">Update Profile</a></li>
</ul>

Jquery:

$(document).ready(function() {
    var  current_page = document.URL;

    if (current_page.match(/dashboard/)){
        $("ul#navigation li:eq(0)").addClass('selected sel');
    }

    else if (current_page.match(/mycoupon/)){
        $("ul#navigation li:eq(1)").addClass('selected sel');
    } 

    else if (current_page.match(/member/)){
        $("ul#navigation li:eq(2)").addClass('selected sel');
    }

    else if (current_page.match(/update/)){
        $("ul#navigation li:eq(3)").addClass('selected sel');
    } 

    else { // don't mark any nav links as selected
        $("ul#navigation li").removeClass('selected sel');
    }
});
```

Comment: It is working for me.

Comment: Oh in my side got stock to 3rd li only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing code for each menu, you can simply use like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current_page = document.URL;
  $("#navigation li  a").filter(function() {
    return current_page.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) > -1
  }).closest("li").addClass("selected sel");
});
```

Comment: Wooh You save my day Anoop Joshi Thanks A lot